# nsfetchedresultscontroller implementation confusing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm having trouble with `NSFetchedResultsController's` methods. I've read the implementation but it doesn't seem to click. Specifically, these methods (from Apple Documentation):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[<#Fetched results controller#> sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[<#Fetched results controller#> sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[<#Fetched results controller#> sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo name];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [<#Fetched results controller#> sectionIndexTitles];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return [<#Fetched results controller#> sectionForSectionIndexTitle:title atIndex:index];
}
```

The things I don't understand are the `sections` and `sectionIndexTitles` properties. I never declared these properties when initializing the `NSFetchedResultsController`, so how does XCode know them and how does it display them without crashing?

Furthermore, in the method

```
NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
        initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
        managedObjectContext:context
        sectionNameKeyPath:nil
        cacheName:@"<#Cache name#>"];
```

I don't understand how to set a `sectionNameKeyPath`. For example, if I wanted to create a to do list with completed and incomplete tasks, how would I differentiate those into 2 sections? Would I need a value in the task entity? And would this value have to be a string/would I have to give it a custom setter?

I would really appreciate it the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
```

This is how many sections you want to display in the table. A section is a group of items that have something in common. They might all begin with the same letter (like in the Contacts app), they might be teams that belong to different leagues, they might be people sectioned by what country they were born in, etc...

2.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

This is how many items belong to the section provided. For instance there might be 3 people born in France and 2 born in Germany. So you go to you fetched results controller to ask it how many objects are in that section and return the number.

3.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

This is the title of the section. "France", "Germany", etc...

If you specified a "sectionKeyPath" in your fetched results controller then the section.name will be the grouped value from the data objects for the path name you gave it.

i.e. sectionKeyPath = countryOfBirth.name;

This will return the name value in the country of birth object on each person in that section.

4.

and

5.

These are both related to the index down the right hand edge of the table. They are optional. I would suggest ignoring these for now until you've got your head around the other methods.

So, to use my example you might do something like this...

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestForEntityName:@"Person"];

NSSortDescriptor *countrySD = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"countryOfBirth.name" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *nameSD = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[countrySD, nameSD]];

NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
    initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
    managedObjectContext:context
    sectionNameKeyPath:@"countryOfBirth.name"
    cacheName:nil];
```

This will then get you something like...

```
- Albania
    - Bob
    - Margaret
- France
    - Alice
    - John
- Zimbabwe
    - Jason
    - Zachary
```

Comment: In your example, what is countryOfBirth.name? If Person is the entity, then countryOfBirth would be the attribute right? So whats the .name?

Comment: CountryOfBirth in this example is a Country entity. That has a name attribute. With. To-one relationship with Person.